# Find the image of an analytic branch $f\left(2i\right)=2+i\cdot \left(\frac{9}{2}\pi \right)$, means, find $I_m\left(f\right)=?$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, branch-points

had a test a few days ago and was not sure about my solution.
Please check it out and tell me if I was wrong, none I asked knew what to do \ others did like me.

EDIT: ( I really hope I am not lying about $f(2i)$, I 99% remember that was the function)
It could be that instead of $i\cdot \left(\frac{9}{2}\pi \right)$ it was: $\left(\frac{9}{2}\pi \right)$, but one of them for sure.

Let $log(z)$ be an analytic branch of $f$.
let $f$ be defined at the domain: $\mathbb{C}\backslash _{R_{\le 0}}$
we know that $f\left(2i\right)=ln(2)+i\cdot \left(\frac{9}{2}\pi \right)$
find the image of $f$

My solution: ( atleast what I tried )
I wrote $f(z)$ as:
$f(z)=ln(R)+i\cdot (\theta + 2\pi k)$, when $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
from here I can understand that k has to be 2, so $\theta$ has to be in the range of $f(2i)$.
which is $3\pi \le \theta <5\pi$
Thus receiving the conclusion of A=$Im(f)$ as of:
$A =${$ \left|z\right|=2,3\pi \le \theta <5\pi$}

Comment: Can you quote the original question? It is not understandable and what is k and k has to be 2?

Comment: Oh sorry, I will try my best to make it as it was, I will update

Comment: @Tim Done :)
Sorry for the confusion, hope it is clear
I dont remember the question words by words since it is a hidden one and I wanted to forget that question, but I have to do it for me to understand my grade

Comment: edited lastly, wanted to make sure, sorry for confusion, the proffessor did not yet show the test \ result will be in two weeks atleast.

Comment: f(2i) is not match with the function, $f(2i)=ln 2+…$?

Comment: ops sorry, forgot the ln, my bad!! did not notice it
Really sorry!!! Will edit!

Comment: It seems that your question is to find a suitable branch cut such that log is analytic. The conclusion A is your solution? It should be open interval $(3\pi,5\pi)$, and |z |>0

Comment: hmm not a suitable branch, but to find the image of $f(z)$
what is open interval? you mean the interval of $\theta$ I wrote?

Comment: I know this already.
But anyway, I think what I did is the answer, although not sure at it, asked 2 more people, they did like me also ( instead of the other two from before ). thanks anyway for the help :)